# How would you relate the arc length and chord length in a circle?

Tags: trigonometry

Diagram: [image]

I need a small hint for this question. I know that arc length $L$ is = $r\theta$ but I dont know how to incorporate d. I tried using cosine rule, but then I get a square root, which is ugly.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right path.
Using cosine rule,
$\color{blue}{d^2 = r^2+r^2-2r^2\cos\theta}  = 2r^2(1-\cos\theta) = 2r^2(2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}) = (2r\sin\frac{\theta}{2})^2$

Here $0<\theta<\pi \Rightarrow \sin\frac{\theta}{2}>0$
So,

$d = 2r\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$

Can you end now?

Comment: Yes, I see. It does work, I was just too scared to try I thought the working would be really ugly

Comment: Yeah, you have the half angle in the final expression. So that is a hint to use the half-angle formula.

Answer (score 1):

$$d=2r\sin\theta/2$$
Derive this by dropping the parpendicular from the center on the chord.

Comment: Nope, if $\theta=0$, then $d=0$.

Comment: That was a silly mistake. I have edited.

Comment: Thank you! This works especially well if you don't know the half-angle formulas. Also shouldn't it be sin?

Comment: Yes I edited it

Comment: Yep I see I was 30 seconds late

Answer (score 1):

Split $OAB$ in two right triangles. Then

$$\frac d2=r\sin\frac\theta2.$$

---

Together with

$$l=r\theta$$ you can eliminate $r$ and

$$\frac dl=\frac{\sin\dfrac\theta2}{\dfrac\theta2}=\text{sinc }\frac\theta 2.$$

Getting the angle from the arc and the chord is especially difficult, as you need to invert the cardinal sine. It is also pretty inaccurate.

Comment: Hi Yves ! Thanks for the edit. By the way, how are you doing in thie terrible time ? Take care. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: safe and sound, thanks for asking. Hope you as well. May the force of Padé with you !

Comment: I cannot resist !

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @Yves Daoust's answer, the solution of the equation
$$\frac dl=\text{sinc}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$$ required numerical methods.

However, you can have a quite decent approximation building around $t=0$ the $[4,4]$ Padé approximant of the rhs. This will give
$$\text{sinc}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\sim \frac{1-\frac{53 }{1584}t^2+\frac{551 }{2661120}t^4 } { 1+\frac{13 }{1584}t^2+\frac{5 }{177408}t^4} $$ and you then just need to solve a quadratic equation in $t^2$.

For you specific case, this would give $t\approx 2.5513976$ while the exact solution is  $t\approx 2.5513962$.

Comment: Claude, I allowed myself a small fix.